# How to insert typescript variable into html element submit method

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Angular 8/Django 3 app. I am trying to add a variable that I retrieve from the server side `client_secret` to the `stripe.confirmCardPayment()` method. I keep getting the error `Property 'client_secret' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`.

**checkout.component.ts**

```
declare var Stripe: any;
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {

  client_secret;
  constructor(){..}

ngOnInit() {

//THIS METHOD BELOW RETRIEVES 'client_secret'
  this.getpaymentintent()

  const stripe = Stripe('xxxx');

  const paymentForm = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  paymentForm.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.client_secret, {      //HOW DO I ADD 'client_secret' here?
      payment_method: 
      ...  }}}

getpaymentintent(){..)}
}
```

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var stripe = Stripe('xxx'); // use your test publishable key
  var elements = stripe.elements();
</script>

<form id="payment-form">
  <div id="card-element">      </div>
  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  <button id="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to member variables in a callback function, you could use the arrow function notation. Try the following

```js
paymentForm.addEventListener('submit', (ev) => {       // <-- arrow function here
  ev.preventDefault();
  stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.client_secret, {
    payment_method: 
    ...  }}}
```

Comment: wow this looks to have done it thank you so much! i would have never removed `function`, do you have a link to somewhere I can read about this?

Comment: It actually depends on what the keyword `this` points among different notations. You could start by seeing here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. Short answer is, in a function defined with `function` keyword, `this` denotes the scope of the function and not the class.